# Is there a master list of user/group permissions in Craft?

Tags: user-groups, permissions

Has anybody compiled (or is it be possible to extract from the system) a master list of all the various permissions one can assign in Craft?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go straight to the source and get the list from [UserPermissionsService->getAllPermissions()](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/services/UserPermissionsService.php#L39).